# PHP - Group Array by a Dynamic number of Keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to use PHP to group an array which has a dynamically generated number of keys.

My query outputs something like this:

```
| employee   | SkillA     | SkillB     |
 ------------+------------+------------
| Person One | 2015-05-04 | -          |
| Person One | -          | 2016-05-01 |
| Person Two | -          | 2016-03-25 |
| Person Two | 2016-04-04 | -          |
```

Which is built from an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1001675 
        [employee] => Person One 
        [SkillA] => 2015-05-04 
        [SkillB] => NULL
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1001675 
        [employee] => Person One 
        [SkillA] => NULL 
        [SkillB] => 2016-05-01 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1006111 
        [employee] => Person Two 
        [SkillA] => NULL 
        [SkillB] => 2016-03-25 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1006111 
        [employee] => Person Two 
        [SkillA] => 2016-04-04 
        [SkillB] => NULL 
    ) 
)
```

But I need to display this:

```
| employee   | SkillA     | SkillB     |
 ------------+------------+------------
| Person One | 2015-05-04 | 2016-05-01 |
| Person Two | 2016-04-04 | 2016-03-25 |
```

Which means my array needs to look like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1001675 
        [employee] => Person One 
        [SkillA] => 2015-05-04 
        [SkillB] => 2016-05-01
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1006111 
        [employee] => Person Two 
        [SkillA] => 2016-04-0
        [SkillB] => 2016-03-25 
    ) 
)
```

I tried to do this by using `GROUP BY` in MySQL (see this question [MySQL - Dynamic Pivot Table Grouping Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218685/)). But having failed I decided to try to group with PHP instead.

There a quite a few SO questions regarding "PHP array grouping" but none seem to do quite what I need. The problem is that the array keys are dynamically generated. They will always contain `[id]`, `[employee]` but these are followed by an undetermined number of "`[skill]`" keys.

I use this to get the names of the headers:

```
// We don't know the names of the headers 
// so loop through all of the array keys to get them

$headers = array();

while ($key = current($data[0])) {
    $header = key($data[0]);
    array_push($headers, $header); // add the header to an array for later use
    echo '<th>' . $header . '</th>'; // write the headers to the table
    next($data[0]);
}
```

So I thought I could do something like this to get the data how I need it:

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        $arr[$item['employee']][$header] = $item;
    }
}
```

But it's not producing an array in the desired format.

Comment: Focus on doing it with MySQL. It is not that complicated.

Comment: how it should group when `Person One` would have three records with one `SkillA`(`2015-05-04`) and several `SkillB` and `SkillC` filled values?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` in my query will prevent more than one value for any "skill" - it only gets the latest "skill date" for each

Answer (score 0):

Let's back to MySQL query

```
select employee, max(SkillA) SkillA, max(SkillB) SkillB 
from t 
group by employee
```

where change `t` to your query

Comment: It's an interesting idea but `max(SkillA) SkillA, max(SkillB) SkillB ` would need to be dynamically generated with only the skill headers from my query.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ID is the same per person, why not use it as an array key?

```
$query = your_database_query;

$aQueryResult = array ( );

while ( $aFetch = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $query ) )
{
    if ( isset ( $aQueryResult[$aFetch['id']] ) )
    {
        $aQueryResult[$aFetch['id']] = array_merge ( array_filter ( $aQueryResult[$aFetch['id']] ), array_filter ( $aFetch ) );
    }
    else
    {
        $aQueryResult[$aFetch['id']] = $aFetch;
    }
}

print_r ( $aQueryResult );
```

This way it doesn't matter how much skill fields you have.

**Edit:**
array_filter removes NULL values and array_merge merges the two arrays together.